# Interactive Debugger Not Starting

Tags: apex, vs-code, apex-debugger

I'm trying to get started with the interactive debugger. I have a sandbox org with my user assigned to a permission set that has the Apex Debug permission. I try to start debugging from VS Code but it never starts. I get the loading bar like it's trying to do something but nothing ever happens. No errors or anything. The loading bar just keeps running but it's like it's hung. I left it alone at took a break and came back 30 minutes later and it's still the same thing. I've also checked the Apex Debugger sessions in the org and nothing shows up.

The blue bar just keeps moving.

https://pasteboard.co/E6WKZw3lq67y.png

Answer (score 0):

When I debug in VS Code, i get this Control where i have to click Play. Then I am able to Debug the Code with the Values from the Debug Log:
[image]

Comment: That control does show up for me but only the "Restart" and "Stop" buttons are enabled. The debug session never actually starts.

Comment: I get exactly the same issue @James. I wish I knew what the reason was.